# Chrome plugin message passing callback undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, callback

I managed to pass a message between two files/instances, namely my popup and my background scripts, but the callback function still returns undefined, so my popup script does not receive a reply. Can somebody assist me? My code is based on [the docs from Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (sender, sendResponse) {
    var resp = {'navURL': "Not set yet"};
    if (sender.greeting === "GetURL") {
      sendResponse(resp);
    }

  });
```

**popup.js**

```
function getURL() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      greeting: "GetURL"
    },
    function (response) {

      // RESPONSE IS UNDEFINED //

      console.log(response);
      alert(response.navURL);
    });
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
    getURL();
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
    {

      "name": "FaceBlock",
      "description": "This extention gets rid of unwanted content on Facebook like sponsored posts, adds or annoying suggestions. The content you wish to see is enlarged for a better and richer social experience.",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
        "http://*.facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*"],
          "css": ["css/popup.css"],
          "js": ["js/jquery.min.js", "js/content.js"],
          "run_at": "document_end",
          "all_frames": true
    }],
      "options_page": "options.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Faceblock"
    },
      "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://www.facebook.com/*",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage"
  ],
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "options_ui": {
        // Required.
        "page": "popup.html",
        // Recommended.
        "chrome_style": true
          // Not recommended; only provided for backwards compatibility,
          // and will be unsupported in a future version of Chrome (TBD).
          //"open_in_tab": true
      },
      "web_accessible_resources": [

    "images/faceblock.jpg",
    "images/seigaiha.png",
    "js/popup.js",
    "icon.png",
    "js/options.js",
    "css/popup.css",
    "popup.html",
    "options.html"
  ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Niels Vermeiren

> ***EDIT: I now have the following with the same problem***

**Background.js**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      sendResponse({msg: "Element " + sender.element + " zijn zichtbaarheid wordt nu: " + sender.checked});

      return true;


  });
```

**Popup.js**

```
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query
    var queryInfo = {
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    };

    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
      if (callback(tabs[0].url)) {
        return resolve();
      } else {
        return reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

function changeFacebook(data) {
  console.log(data);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    "changeFacebook",
    data,
    function (response //undefined) {
      console.log(response.msg); // UNDEFINED

    });
}






document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


  var callback = function getCurrentTab(tab) {
    if (tab == "https://www.facebook.com/") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }


  getCurrentTabUrl(callback).then(function () {
    alert('on facebook');
    $('.section').hide();

  }, function () {
    alert('not on facebook');
  });


  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var check = this.checked;

  var data = {
    'element': id,
    'checked': check
  };

  changeFacebook(data);
});

  $('.menuItem').hide();

  $('.menuItem:first').show();

  jQuery('.navitem').on('click', function () {

    var value = $(this).html().toLocaleLowerCase();
    jQuery('.menuItem').hide();
    jQuery('#' + value).show();

  });
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to set background persistent to true in your manifest?

Comment: I would like it to be event based, so i honestly don't know why it should be set to true (could be). It does not resolve my problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to doc here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

In your background.js, it should be

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  ... 
});
```

Since you are missing the last argument, what you really have is this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  ...
});
```

So your code pretty much renamed `request => sender`, `sender => sendResponse`.

Therefore, you are trying to invoke `sender` as a function. But the actual `sendResponse` callback function is undefined. If you inspect your background page (see tips for how), you should see the error.

**Tips:**

When developing chrome extension, you can `Inspect views: background page` in the `chrome://extensions` page if you have any background page running.

When your popup is opened, you can inspect the popup page just you normally do.

And you can throw debuggers wherever you want, and you will be able to play around with it.

**Edit:**

So I have tested your code, the issue is just missing argument as I stated above. I also noticed the doc says the first two arguments are optional (not sure what the fuzz that is). But if you change your code to as below, it will work.

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var resp = {'navURL': "Not set yet"};
  if (request.greeting === "GetURL") {
    sendResponse(resp);
  }
});
```

**Popup.js**

```
function getURL() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    greeting: "GetURL"
  },
  function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response.navURL);
  });
}
```

**To test it**

1. Go to the background page inspect, and paste in the background page snippet.
2. Go to the popup page inspect (open your popup, and right click within the popup, then choose inspect)
3. Paste in the popup page snippet
4. In the popup page inspect, call `getURL()`

Comment: More accurately, what the OP is using as `sendResponse` is an Object (a [MessageSender Object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender)) which is not a function. Thus, while it is defined, it is not defined as a function.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your answer to correct this minor issue. Then I can delete my comment.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) indicates that the first argument of the function is optional.

Comment: Yes and no. In explaining it, I would suggest that you stick with the parameter names which the OP used (not throughout your answer, just when explaining the error).  There is nothing inherent in the names of the parameters, as the question demonstrates. The fact that we generally use `sendResponse` is just a convention. We could use `someNameWhichHasNoothingToDoWithWhatItIsReallyDoing` if we really wanted to. We don't do so because using a name that describes the purpose of the parameter is good practice.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko, True, the documentation says that. However, providing a message to `runtime.sendMessage()` is mandatory (error if no message). However, the OP dos actually send a message, thus the parameter will exist. The OP is using `sender` as the functionality of the first parameter, usually `message`.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I used all the optional params now but still got the same issue. Pretty weird :)

Comment: @NielsVermeiren can you inspect what those arguments are in the background page and kindly post them?

Comment: Sure can, give me a minute.

Comment: Request, sender and sendResponse seem to be null. Everything in popup.js is fine!

Comment: @NielsVermeiren so the listener function is invoked for sure? but all the arguments are null? doesn't sound right to me. How did you find out they are null?

Comment: @EdmundLee Indeed that does not make any sense, it was due to the many small changes some people requested here. I reverted it back and will update you.

Comment: Review the parameters of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage): `"changeFacebook"` is not a valid extension id (you don't even need the id if you are sending a message within the same extension)

Comment: @NielsVermeiren please see my edit. I have tested it and it's working fine.